# How to solve this error in a loop: "replacement has 30 rows, data has 29"?

Tags: r, data-structures

I am an extreme amateur in R so I know for sure that I am messing something up but I am unable to figure it out from google.

I am working with the ncaahoopR package. I am attempting to use the function get_schedule with dict$ESPN as the input to pull the entire NCAA basketball schedule but I am running into this error: "Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "game_id", value = c("401169778", "401172236",  : 
  replacement has 30 rows, data has 29"

when using the below code

```
for (i in dict$ESPN){
  get_schedule(i)
}
```

The result if I run the function with an index of the vector is below.

```
     game_id       date           opponent location team_score opp_score    record
1  401172259 2019-11-05             Bryant        A         73        71 1-0 (0-0)
2  401171927 2019-11-09           Canisius        H         75        68 2-0 (0-0)
3  401172062 2019-11-13         Quinnipiac        H         70        68 3-0 (0-0)
4  401172260 2019-11-19       Sacred Heart        A         63        84 3-1 (0-0)
5  401170379 2019-11-23               NJIT        H         79        63 4-1 (0-0)
6  401170932 2019-11-26       UMass Lowell        A         63        75 4-2 (0-0)
7  401172261 2019-11-30               Navy        H         56        76 4-3 (0-0)
8  401172262 2019-12-04          Merrimack        H         82        55 5-3 (0-0)
9  401170975 2019-12-07        Stony Brook        A         63        79 5-4 (0-0)
10 401168464 2019-12-10         St. John's        A         71        82 5-5 (0-0)
11 401168277 2019-12-28               Duke        A         50        75 5-6 (0-0)
12 401170216 2020-01-02       Rhode Island        H         85        75 6-6 (0-0)
13 401172263 2020-01-07 Johnson & Wales RI        H         79        53 7-6 (0-0)
14 401172264 2020-01-17               Yale        A         56        70 7-7 (0-1)
15 401172265 2020-01-24               Yale        H         62        73 7-8 (0-2)
16 401172266 2020-01-31            Cornell        H         74        63 8-8 (1-2)
17 401172267 2020-02-01           Columbia        H         72        66 9-8 (2-2)
18 401172268 2020-02-07          Dartmouth        H         NA        NA          
19 401172269 2020-02-08            Harvard        H         NA        NA          
20 401172270 2020-02-14       Pennsylvania        A         NA        NA          
21 401172271 2020-02-15          Princeton        A         NA        NA          
22 401172272 2020-02-21           Columbia        A         NA        NA          
23 401172273 2020-02-22            Cornell        A         NA        NA          
24 401172274 2020-02-28          Princeton        H         NA        NA          
25 401172275 2020-02-29       Pennsylvania        H         NA        NA          
26 401172276 2020-03-06            Harvard        A         NA        NA          
27 401172277 2020-03-07          Dartmouth        A         NA        NA
```

I am pretty certain that it has to do with the data structures but I am not familiar enough to understand why so I would appreciate some help.  Please let me know if I can provide any more useful information.

Comment: The data is available in the `ncaahoopR` package on github. First test the function on one team. What does `get_schedule(dict$ESPN[1])` give you? Since you never save the result of `get_schedule()`, your loop retrieves the schedule for each team and then discards it. You say the output is 7x28 (7 rows by 28 columns), but the error message talks about 30 and 29 rows. Are you showing us all of your code?

Comment: Hi @dcarlson, I have added the output above for when the code is run with only one team. I have tried saving the output and have failed in that regard with the same error as above. The error message talks about >30 rows I believe because I am attempting to run it on multiple teams which should result in over 30 rows. I figured that since the error is showing up without saving the output that it lies in the loop. Please let me know if I can give you anymore information to help.

Comment: Hi @Tung, thanks for your help as well. As the other commenter noted, the data is available through GitHub, it is not my own data.

Comment: Try `allsched <- lapply(dict$ESPN, get_schedule)`. That should give you a list that contains the schedule for each team as a separate data frame, e.g. `allsched[[1]]` will be the schedule for the first team. This is an efficient way to work with multiple data frames but it requires some effort to learn how to take advantage of it.

Comment: Unfortunately this yields the same error. Is it possible that the issue is being caused by different sizes of schedules? So some teams will have 29 rows while others have 30?

Answer (score 0):

re-install the libraries. i had the same issue and posted on the github issues thread.